# Неверная кодировка JSON. Android - httpclient.execute(HttpGet, ResponseHandler)

Tags: java, android, кодировка, http, httpclient

Имеется сервер, который работает с GET запросами. В андроид-приложении я получаю JSON,  в котором будут встречаться кириллические символы. Для начала я хочу вытянуть строку с json'ом:

```
    final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet();
    final ResponseHandler<String> responsehandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    result = httpclient.execute(httpget, responsehandler);
```

в итоге, в строке result все кириллические символы заменяются кашей. Где можно указать кодировку, чтобы  httpclient.execute(HttpGet, ResponseHandler<String>) работал корректно с кириллицей?

ps Если вытягивать json [руками](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/), символы отображаются нормально.

Спасибо за внимание! 
**UPD:** Кодировка отправляемого json UTF8

> Чтобы иметь возможность указать
> кодировку json, нужно написать свою
> реализацию ResponseHandler

Благодарю, Dr Zoidberg, это ответ на мой вопрос! Хотя остается загадкой, почему стандартная реализация не захотела работать с кириллицей в UTF8.
Ваш вариант вытаскивания json  и  вариант приведенный мной по ссылке схожи, за тем исключением, что ваш не кидает предупреждений и меньше по объему.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня есть подозрения, что json в кодировке, отличной от UTF-8, иначе строка должна нормально прочитаться.

Чтобы иметь возможность указать кодировку json, нужно написать свою реализацию ResponseHandler.

Но на мой взгляд проще делать так:

```
final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
```

В последней строке заменить UTF-8 на кодировку json.

Comment: кодировка в которой сервер посылает Json - UTF8

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой что и товарищ темы. может кому поможет. `json_encode` принимает только UTF8 по сути.

Получал данные запросом с базы, кодил `json_encode`. Несмотря на то что база в `UTF8_general_ci` и файл php тоже UTF8. Json_encode возвращал `null`. Хотя `mb_detect_encoding()` упорно показывал что с базы приходит UTF8. вообщем исправил так:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'cp1251'");
```

перед запросом в базу.

Answer (score 0):

Вижу что у вас GET запрос, у меня была похожая проблема с POST (может кому-то пригодится) на базе вместо кирилицы было "??????".
Вот решение:

1. нужно  все файлы апи перевести в кодировку utf8- без BOM
2. после `$db->connect()` сделать `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`
3. отправлять json в правильной кодировке.

Я думаю, ключевым моментом является

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Вот может кому-то пригодится парсер с POST

```
package com.library;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.util.Log;

    public class JSONParser {

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {

        }

        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
                HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
                httpParams.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(2000));
                httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", HTTP.UTF_8);

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8));


                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "UTF-8"));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                Log.e("JSON", json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

> JSON, в котором будут встречаться кириллические символы

Согласно [1], JSON не **должен** содержать неэкранированные символы вне ASCII диапазона.

> Где можно указать кодировку

Согласно [2], JSON **должен бы** быть закодирован как UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE или UTF-32BE. По умолчанию принимается UTF-8. Следовательно, результат необходимо преобразовать, как предлагается на [стековерфловочке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071320/539484). Замечание: код по ссылке рассматривает нераскодированный JSON (`application/json`) как String, в том время как правильно его рассматривать, как `byte []`.

1. [Спецификация JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) § 2.5
2. [Спецификация JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) § 3